# Multiple SQL joins on 2 different databases with multiple tables

Tags: sql, multiple-databases

I'm attempting to create the correct set of joins on multiple tables across two different databases but i keep running into syntax errors ("Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join') whenever i run the following query. What's causing this and how can i get around it?

```
BEGIN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @myNumber as VarCHAR(MAX)
SET @myNumber = CAST(@myNumber AS INT)
DECLARE @myBook INT;
SELECT  @myBook = myBook from locationMaster WHERE myNumber = @myNumber AND (SearchType='S' OR myType ='CS' OR myType ='TS');

;WITH fifthTable AS
        (
            SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (   
                        PARTITION BY 
                            serial
                        ORDER BY
                            CASE encode.Primaryencode 
                                WHEN 'A' THEN 1 
                                WHEN 'P' THEN 2
                            END,
                            isr.EffectiveDate DESC
                    ) AS 'RowNumber',
                encode.encode,
                ISNULL(isr.myPrice, '0.00') as myPrice,
                isr.workItemNumber, 
                PE.myEventID as EventID,
                im.Description

            FROM [DB1].[dbo].[firstTable] as firstTableAlias
                Join alias1 im 
                on firstTableAlias.SIN = im.SIN
                and firstTableAlias.MaxExpirationDate > GetDate()
                and firstTableAlias.myBook = @myBook
                JOIN secondTable isr 
                ON (firstTableAlias.workItemNumber = isr.workItemNumber
                AND isr.myBook = @myBook 
                AND isr.ExpirationDate > GetDate())
                JOIN thirdTable encode 
                ON encode.workItemNumber = isr.workItemNumber
                AND ( encode.Primaryencode='A' OR (encode.Primaryencode='P' AND LEN(encode.encode) = 12) )
                JOIN fourthTable AS ia 
                ON ia.PriceBookItem = im.workItemNumber 

                ( 
                join [secondDB].[dbo].myPE as PE
                on [secondDB].[dbo].[DG].ID = PE.ID)
            WHERE 

                and PE.myEventID = 5
        )

        SELECT
            [Description]           
                
        FROM fifthTable
        WHERE RowNumber = 1
END
```

I tried fully qualifying the database names, giving different aliases, moving the joins in different orders, re-writing the syntax, creating a temporary table to do a select upon, even parametrizing the join that it's failing on to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parenthesis you have wrapped around the this join:

(
join [secondDB].[dbo].myPE as PE
on [secondDB].[dbo].[DG].ID = PE.ID)

Comment: That just gives me a syntax error on [secondDB].[dbo].[DG].ID

Comment: The multi-part identifier "[secondDB].[dbo].[DG].ID " could not be bound.

Comment: [secondDB].[dbo].[DG] isn't in your from clause, how can it be in the On clause?